# Magento restrict products by postalcode

Tags: php, magento, product

I'm working on a magento shop for local products, because they are local i'd like to sell some products in some regions.

There are heavy and easy stuff, so i want to ship heavy stuff to postalcode x and y, and all the other to x,y,z.

Is there a plugin that restrict products to some postal codes? Or an "easy" options? Maybe by product attributes?

I hope my question is clear, thanks in forward.

Comment: Did you found any free extensions ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this free shipping restriction extension:

> http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/15768/

There are several other paid ones also:

> http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/shipping-filter-by-zip-code-city-extension.html
>   http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/shipping-restrictions-8387.html

Comment: all these become paid extensions now, please suggest any free extensions.